# Is it possible to use MongoDB as an embedded database?

Tags: c++, mongodb, embedded-database

As the title says I like to embedd the MongoDB server into my own C++ application. I haven't found this mode in the documentation. What I was looking for is something like SQLite or Firebird in the embedded mode. Is this also possible with MongoDB? (Without programming it myself).

Comment: I just came across UnQLite , but I know nothing about using it, yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to embed MongoDB right now - but on the wishlist of many people.

Comment: The truth is tough:-) Do you possibly know any other embedded nosql database?

Answer (score 6):

You should consider [EJDB](http://ejdb.org/).

EJDB is the C library based on modified version of Tokyo Cabinet. JSON representation of queries and data implemented with API based on C BSON, MongoDB-like queries and overall philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

I like tokyo cabinet. It is flexible document storage like mongodb. It also comes with some nifty full text searching abilities and a small memory footprint.

Tokyo Cabinet:
http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/

I've also created an objective-c wrapper (in case you wanted to embed it in an osx/ios app).
https://github.com/isaact/TSDocDB

Answer (score 0):

Though it is in java, you may want to take a look at [fongo](https://github.com/foursquare/fongo). Which is a in-memory embedded implementation of MongoDB in Java.

Comment: Seems others a trying to get mongo embedded as well, but I would like to have it in C++, Thanks anyway