# mongoDB for iOS project

Tags: ios, mongodb, nosql

I have searched in google about mongoDB and iOS but found nothing. Can I use mongoDB in my iOS projects? How to plug in mongoDB to my iOS project if it possible. thanks..

Comment: MongoDB is not an embedded database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this SO answer [Is it possible to use MongoDB as an embedded database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902005/is-it-possible-to-use-mongodb-as-an-embedded-database) it seems that you cannot embed MongoDB - even though a lot of people are asking for that feature.  So no matter how much you like it you will have to look for a different solution.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that install mongodb on iphone is good idea even if it possible. It is not so light weight database. And it will lead to various problems, like repair database after failover, user can stop database manually. I suggest to use [sqlite](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application) database instead. It will be much simpler.

Mongodb good fit for backend of mobile app, but not supposed to be used on mobile devices.

Comment: I know that CoutchDB can be used in iphone, so why mongoDB can't be embedded in iphone?

Comment: CouchDB is not MongoDB, that's why. If you want to use CouchDB, go ahead: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/iOS-Couchbase